# How to get uploaded image path in express js node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working with express js

I have uploaded image in ROOT/public/uploads/fullsize/ folder

Now i want to image path  of uploaded image in web url like [IMAGE_URL](http://support24hour.com/workplace2/vent/public/uploads/fullsize/youruploadedfile)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your permissions are set up in your server but typically the public folder is housed at the root so /public/javascripts/test.js would be localhost:3000/javascripts/test.js. so assuming all permissions are the same you should be able to access it at localhost:3000/uploads/fullsize/

If you are saving images you might look at MongoDB or Cloudinary. Uploading to the public directory could open you to security risks. Plus it is probably cheaper to let a free service like Cloudinary handle the storage space.